# Egress packets do not use non-default routing table

Tags: ip, routing

I made a custom routing table named `test`:

```
# ip route show table test
default via 10.10.10.126 dev eth0
#
```

As seen above, it contains only a single route. As a next step, I made a rule where traffic from IP address 10.10.10.1(10.10.10.1/25 is configured to `eth0` interface) will check the routing table `test`:

```
# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
1000:   from 10.10.10.1 lookup test
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
#
```

However, if I execute `ping 2.2.2.2`, then connect system call immediately reports that "Network is unreachable". Why is that so if default route in table `test` is present? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your system have multiple addresses? What happens if you do `ping -I 10.10.10.1 2.2.2.2`? What is the result of `ip route get 2.2.2.2`?

Comment: If the packet is originating from the router itself, you should use `ip rule add iif lo table test`. According to `man 8 ip` if the interface is loopback the rule matches packets originating from this host.

Comment: @gnp the source interface should only be `lo` if the destination address is an address on the local host.

Comment: @Patrick Specifying the source IP address for ping fixed it. Thanks! However, what is the difference between `ip route get 2.2.2.2` and `ip route show match 2.2.2.2`? Both should show the matching route in routing table, shouldn't they?